# Should I test the private functions of a Javascript plugin?

Tags: javascript, tdd, qunit, pavlov

I am trying to write test driven Javascript. Testing each function, I know, is crucial. But I came to a stumbling block, in that the plugin which I am writing needs to have some private functions. I cannot peek into how they are functioning. What would I need to do if I want to keep my code well tested without changing the structure of it too much? (I am ok with exposing some API, though within limits.)

I am using sinon, QUnit, and Pavlov.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing *test driven development* (as suggested by the tags) each line of production code is first justified by failing test case.

In other words the existence of each and every line of your production code is implicitly tested because without it some test must have failed. That being said you can safely assume that private function/lambda/closure is already tested from the definition of TDD.

If you have a private function and you are wondering how to test it, it means you weren't doing TDD on the first place - and now you have a problem.

To sum up - never write production code before the test. If you follow this rule, every line of code is tested, no matter how deep it is.

Comment: Someone had to say it before I realized how true it is once again. Thanks.

Comment: @picardo - this does not answer the core question which is how to test _private_ functions.  picardo made a conceptual error by suggesting defining tests afterwords.  But that was not the core of the question, which is disappointing because it would be good to get a real answer for that.